# How if statements literally works?

Tags: if-statement, compiler-construction, conditional-statements, interpreter

I was wondering how an `if statement` or `conditional statements` works behind the scenes when executed.

Consider an example like this:

```java
if (10 > 6) {
    // Some code
}
```

How does the compiler or interpreter knows that the number 10 is greater than 6 or 6 is less than 10?

Comment: I answer about "how the compiler or the interpreter knows", the others about "how an if statement (…) works (…) when executed", which is after the compiler is done with it. I don't know if you want to know more about how a compiler works (for which I left you some links), or perhaps you are more interested in how the CPU actually executes the instructions. Consider asking more specific questions. Also consider the sister sites, such as cs.stackexchange.com, softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, electronics.stackexchange.com, etc.. depending on your interest. This one focuses on programming.

Answer (score 2):

At some point near the end of the compilation, the compiler will convert the above in to [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) similar to:

```
start:                      # This is a label that you can reference
    mov ax, 0ah             # Store 10 in the ax register
    mov bx, 06h             # Store 6 in the bx register
    cmp ax, bx              # Compare ax to bx
    jg  inside_the_brackets # 10 > 6? Goto `inside_the_brackets`
    jmp after_the_brackets  # Otherwise skip ahead a little
inside_the_brackets:
    # Some code - stuff inside the {} goes here
after_the_brackets:
    # The rest of your program. You end up here no matter what.
```

I haven't written in assembler in years so I know that's a jumble of different varieties, but the above is the gist of it. Now, that's an inefficient way to structure the code, so a smart compiler might write it more like:

```
start:                      # This is a label that you can reference
    mov ax, 0ah             # Store 10 in the ax register
    mov bx, 06h             # Store 6 in the bx register
    cmp ax, bx              # Compare ax to bx
    jle after_the_brackets # 10 <= 6? Goto `after_the_brackets`
inside_the_brackets:
    # Some code - stuff inside the {} goes here
after_the_brackets:
    # The rest of your program. You end up here no matter what.
```

See how that reversed the comparison, so instead of `if (10 > 6)` it's more like `if (10 <= 6)`? That removes a `jmp` instruction. The logic is identical, even if it's no longer *exactly* what you originally wrote. There -- now you've seen an "optimizing compiler" at work.

Every compiler you're likely to have heard of has a million tricks to convert code you write into assembly language that *acts* the same, but that the CPU can execute more efficiently. Sometimes the end result is barely recognizable. Some of the optimizations are as simple as what I just did, but others are fiendishly clever and people have earned PhDs in this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Kirk Strauser answer is correct. However you ask:

> How does the compiler or interpreter knows that the number 10 is greater than 6 or 6 is less than 10?

Some optimizer compilers can see that `10 > 6` is a constant expression equivalent to `true`, and not emit any check or jump at all. If you are asking how they do that, well…

I'll explain the process in steps that hopefully are easy to understand. I'm covering no advanced topics.

---

The build process will start by parsing your code document according to the syntax of the language.

The syntax of the language will define how to interpret the text of the document (think a string with your code) as a series of symbols or tokens (e.g. keywords, literals, identifiers, operators…). In this case we have:

1. a `if` symbol.
2. a `(` symbol.
3. a `10` symbol.
4. a `>` symbol".
5. a `6` symbol.
6. a `)` symbol.
7. a `{` symbol.
8. and a `}` symbol.

*I'm assuming comments, newlines and white-space do not generate symbols in this language.*

From the series of symbols, it will build a tree-like memory structure (see [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) according to the rules of the language.

The tree will say that your code is:

- An "if statement", that has two children:

  - A conditional (a boolean expression), which is a greater than comparison that has two children:

    - A constant literal integer 10
    - A constant literal integer 6
  - A body (a set of statements), in this case empty.

Then the compiler can look at that tree and figure out how to optimize it, and emit code in the target language (let us say machine code).

The optimization process will see that the conditional does not have variables, it is composed entirely of constants that are known at compile time. Thus it can compute the equivalent value and use that. Which leaves us with this:

- An "if statement", that has two children:

  - A conditional (a boolean expression), which is a literal true.
  - A body (a set of statements), in this case empty.

Then it will see that we have a conditional that is always true, and thus we don't need it. Thus it replaces the if statement with the set of statements in its body. Which are none, we have optimized the code away to nothing.

*You can imagine how the process would then go over the tree, figuring out what is the equivalent in the target language (again, let us say, machine code), and emitting that code until it has gone over the whole tree.*

---

I want to mention that intermediate languages and JIT (just in time) compiling has become very common. See [Understanding the differences: traditional interpreter, JIT compiler, JIT interpreter and AOT compiler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246094/understanding-the-differences-traditional-interpreter-jit-compiler-jit-interp).

My description of how the build process works is a toy textbook example. I would like to encourage to learn further of the topic. I'll suggest, in this order:

- [Computerphile Compilers with Professor Brailsford video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzH6n4zXuckoJaMwuI1fhr5n8cJL18hYd).
- The good old [Dragon
  Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3A_Principles%2C_Techniques%2C_and_Tools) [[pdf](http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/94-95/1/ce414-2/resources/root/Text%20Books/Compiler%20Design/Alfred%20V.%20Aho,%20Monica%20S.%20Lam,%20Ravi%20Sethi,%20Jeffrey%20D.%20Ullman-Compilers%20-%20Principles,%20Techniques,%20and%20Tools-Pearson_Addison%20Wesley%20(2006).pdf)], and other books such as "How To Create Pragmatic, Lightweight Languages" and "Parsing with Perl 6 Regexes and Grammars".
- Finally [CS 6120: Advanced Compilers: The
  Self-Guided Online
  Course](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6120/2020fa/self-guided/)
  which is not about parsing, because it presumes you already know
  that.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to actually check that is implemented in hardware. To be more specific, it will subtract 10-6 (which is one of the basic instructions that processors can do), and if the result is less than or equal to 0 then it will jump to the end of the block (comparing numbers to zero and jumping based on the result are also basic instructions). If you want to learn more, the keywords to look for are "instruction set architecture", and "assembly".

Comment: It's not done by subtraction. Typically there's a comparison instruction that yields a result, or performs a jump, depending on whether one operand is greater than the other. If it used subtraction, then something like `INT_MAX > INT_MIN` would fail, since the subtraction would overflow.

Comment: @KeithThompson The processor sets several flags when it does arithmetic, which includes an overflow bit. `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` will set that bit, which the processor uses in conjunction with the wrapping result of the subtraction to know which is bigger. The ISA that is commonly taught in universities doesn't have an instruction that directly compares numbers with each other, because 32 bits doesn't leave enough room for control codes to do lots of things in one like that.

Comment: Which ISA is commonly taught these days? x86 has a full set of comparisons for evaluating the output of a `cmp` instruction.

Comment: They taught me the ARM architecture, because it's simple enough to explain the whole thing in a semester. In the class I took, we had to be able to encode and decode every instruction between binary and assembly, and write code implementing various algorithms. From the documentation, it says that cmp is implemented as a subtraction where the result is thrown out, so an if statement like in the question would be implemented as a cmp followed by some kind of jump

Comment: Little sad that I'm losing reputation for parroting stuff I just learned a year or two ago XD

Comment: I suggest to edit the answer to add the caveat that it depends on the instruction set.

Comment: @LionelFoxcroft The stuff you learned a year or two ago is incomplete. It may well be true that the ARM code generated for a comparison like that would subtract the operands and then use the resulting condition codes, but it's not the case for other architectures. A similar `if` statement (not using constants) compiled with gcc for x86_64 uses a `cmpl` comparison instruction, not a subtraction.